# Looking for which formula to use in probability?

Tags: probability

In East Baton Rouge, Louisiana, 88% of all households have a LED TVs, 25% of all households have Wii. The probability that a household has a LED TV given that it has Wii is 58%. What is the probability that a household has both LED TV and Wii?

I'm a little confused on the way this question is written, because I'm understanding that its 88% LED tv, 25% with wii, then the probability of having an LED and a Wii is 58%. Is the question asking for both TV and Wii, or an LED with a Wii? If so, what formula would be best used? I would think it would be =p(a) + p(b) - p(a | b), but I'm not sure thats correct.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You have the formula

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

You can rearrange the terms to get what you need

Answer (score 0):

You are given $\Pr(LED) = 0.88$, $\Pr(Wii) = 0.25$, and $\Pr(LED \mid Wii) = 0.58$.  You need to find $\Pr(LED \cap Wii)$.

Remember that $\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B \mid A) = \Pr(B)\Pr(A \mid B)$.